# How to restart or reload Dovecot via doveadm

Tags: dovecot

I'm looking for a command able to either restart/reload or if dovecot is not running, starting Dovecot to activate changed configuration triggered by external, non-interactive tool.

Answer (score 3):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/451406/where-did-etc-init-d-dovecot-go-in-14-04 tells:

`doveadm reload` - in 14.04 the initscript was removed for not understandable reasons.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question.

Comment: `doveadm reload` works and thus answers the question

Answer (score -1):

When `dovecot` has been installed some OS-specific shell-scripts are installed too. Most unix-like OSes have startup script that can accept an argument like `start|stop|restart|reload`.  For linuxes that script usually reside in the `/etc/init.d/` catalog. Find it and look inside for further ideas.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is not having these.

Comment: `sudo service dovecot restart` should be proper way for `ubuntu`.

Comment: Should, but not doing. If's not running it fails.

Comment: This does not answer the question on how to use doveadm.